# Add a subscript in the bottom right corner of a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add a sub script to an html table cell so that it looks like this:

[image]

(The 5 centred in the cell and the 99 at the bottom right corner)

Here is some sample html:

```
<table class="yearTable">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="dayCell">5
            <div class="daySubscript">99</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS I am using:

```
.yearTable td{
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.dayCell 
{
    color:Black;
    background-color:Aqua;
    position: relative;
}

.daySubscript {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
      z-index: 10;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

The problem is that the subscript shows in the top right corner in IE8 and doesn't show at all in firefox

Sample output in IE:

[image]

I tried moving the test in cell into a separate div and I could overlay them but not offset them.

Comment: I don't have a solution off-hand, but relative & absolute position like that DOES NOT WORK in table cells, sorry! Its a quirk of the table rendering. Basically, you can't put relative on the TD and try to absolutely position child elements.

Comment: td nodes do not support relative positioning. You need to add a wrapping div element inside your td with 100% width and height.

Comment: And you have `left:0` and `top:0;`, when it should be `right:0; bottom:0;`

Comment: If you want the 99 at the bottom, why are you setting the top to zero? Set the bottom to zero.

Comment: Why are using tables anyway?

Comment: When displaying tabular data, tables are fine semantically (if you don't mind frustrating quirks with styling).

Comment: @CodyGuldner - for the reasons of trying to shrinkwrap a div around two floated divs and the hacks required to get that working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try positioning your element bottom right,

To see this work : http://jsfiddle.net/bfSVk/

```
.daySubscript {
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0; /* top: 0; */
    right:0; /* left: 0; */
    z-index: 10;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.yearTable td{
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative; /* establish relationship with children position absolute */
}

.yearTable {
    position:relative;
    /* establish relationship with children-children position absolute */
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that almost works. The issue is in firefox it places the `99` at the bottom right corner of the browser screen not the `td` IE8 and Chrome work ok.

Comment: Try fixing relationship with parent TD, making it position:relative. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update but that didn't seem to make any difference. FF still places the 99 in the corner of the screen

Comment: Strangley that works on FF in jsFiddle but not when I use the exact same code in my webpage on FF, where the text is slightly outside the table cell. I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Something must be overriding your styling.

Answer (score 0):

There's an sub element in html specifically for subscript, try using that and see how it looks without applying any style to it.

[Edited with alternative solution below]

```
  .dayCell sub {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
```

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/functionfirst/hjyvJ/

This alternative solution uses your original position absolute but without setting top/left position and instead uses margin to offset the subscript text. This method takes the  out of the document workflow but doesn't set its position *relative* to an element since you're not specifying a top/left position.

Comment: +1 from me - Thanks for the pointer I have tried that. It is not a perfect solution because it moves the `5` to the left and the `99` is not bang in the corner. If I have no other option then I may be forced to use this.

Comment: The problem with this is the size of my `td` may change so I want a method to place it in the corner regardless of size

Answer (score 0):

put that,  i changed the top value to 10 and it works. Try,

```
.daySubscript {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 0;  
      z-index: 10;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: That didn't give the desired effect the 99 is outside the bounds of the table cell